# Can I "extend" the "value" binding in Knockout to do simple character substitution?

Tags: knockout.js, character-encoding

I have a Knockout website where I'm capturing user input in various `input` and `textarea` fields. I'd like to hook into the "value" binding somehow to do some pre-processing on the text that the user enters. (For example, I want to replace "smart quotes" with straight quotes).

The reason I want to do this is that I'm ultimately going to store this text in an Oracle database whose database character set is an 8-bit character set (and I can't change that). So, any Unicode characters that the user types that cannot be translated into that character set are replaced by the '¿'character when the text is stored in the database.

The most common instances are smart quotes (in text pasted from Word or Outlook), and certain symbols such as the Euro symbol. For most of these, there is an acceptable replacement that I could easily use.

My plan would be to intercept the user's text before it gets to the database, and do some simple substitutions. I don't want to scatter that code all over my application, and since all the text is coming via KO binding, it seems like that might be a good central place to do that.

Anyone done this? Any pointers? Alternative schemes?

Comment: How about creating an [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)?

Comment: @Adrian: that would certainly work, though it would mean that I'd need to decorate all of my bound observables across the whole application, which is what I hoped to avoid. Ideally I'd like to make a single change that affects *all* text entered so there's no chance I'll miss one.

Comment: Sounds to me like this should be a feature implemented on the server, rather than on the client. The single change that affects all entered text should be a sanitation step prefacing any write to the DB.

Comment: Do you use `value` with the `valueUpdate` option?

Comment: @MichaelBest: No. I'm not sure how that would help?

Comment: @user3297291: Actually, I agree, but the code / technology stack I'm using doesn't lend itself to that. I can't really mess with the back-end unfortunately.

Comment: @GaryMcGill I think your own answer is a nice implementation (upvoted), but I still think you're going to run in to trouble if you don't sanitize your data server side. What's going to happen if a tech-savy user manually posts incorrect data from their browser's console?

Comment: @user3297291: Exactly what happens how: the default character-set translation will turn their "smart" quotes into upside-down question marks. Not ideal, but since it's not a security issue, I'm not going to worry too much. (It's an intranet site with a small set of users who are most definitely **not** likely to try that anyway :-)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got something working - though I'm not convinced that it's a robust solution.

I actually replaced the `init` method of the built-in `value` binding with something that does the character-translation whenever a value is written:

(*note: the code below is typescript rather than plain javascript*)

```
    const originalInit = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;

    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init = (
        element: any,
        valueAccessor: () => any,
        allBindingsAccessor: KnockoutAllBindingsAccessor,
        viewModel: any,
        bindingContext: KnockoutBindingContext
    ): void => {

        const wrappedValueAccessor = () => {
            const observable = valueAccessor();
            return ko.computed({
                read: () => ko.unwrap(observable),
                write: (newValue) => { observable(to8Bit(newValue)); }
            });
        };

        originalInit(element, wrappedValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    };
```

(`to8Bit` is my function that does the character replacement).

Change my mind... :-)

Comment: Use `ko.pureComputed` instead of `ko.computed` here. Otherwise the computed won't ever get cleaned up. Also, you should call `valueAccessor` within the read function to capture all dependencies: `read: () => ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())`.

Comment: @MichaelBest: Thanks. I'm not *too* worried about the computed not being cleaned up since there won't be that many of them created per page, and the page lifetime is small (it's not a SPA), but good shout nonetheless.

Comment: @MichaelBest: Re your second point... This just makes me think I shouldn't be messing with this stuff, because I don't really get why moving the invocation of `valueAccessor` inside the function would make it more likely to capture the dependencies. I get that it would be invoked "later", and that it would be invoked multiple times, but... is it ever going to return a different value? [I really wish I could look at the source for the Knockout library to see exactly what it does].

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom binding handler that will wrap around knockout's binding handlers and you can add there your custom logic.

For example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customValueHandler= {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

// setup what happens when the binding initializes
// my custom logic here    


// call knockouts value bind init
ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

},
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

// setup what happens when the observable update
// my custom logic here   

// you can then call knockouts update part of default handler
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

This way you can use the default functionality of the original "value","text" or any other knockout built-in binding while also wrapping around it your own custom logic.
This does mean ofcourse you will have to re-write your data-binds to your new custom handler.

Comment: Thanks. So close :-) That last part ("you will have to re-write your data-binds") is unfortunate. I'm currently experimenting to see if I can simply overwrite the "value" binding with a custom version...

Comment: I prefer not to mess with 3rd party stuff directly usually, unless some kind of un-addressed bug exists, but hey its your case, you know what you need better than me!